# Different statements depending on exit status of code

Tags: python, exit-code

This is a general question not pertaining to a code I've written. I was wondering how you get a code to print out something like,
`script successful` if it had an exit status of `0` or `script failed` if it doesn't. I know I've read that somewhere before but I can't recall where. I'm just looking for the python function that handles the exit codes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would organize your code into functions, like:

```
def download_image(url):
    # code to get image goes here
    # save image to disk
    # get file size or check if it exists
    if file_ok:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then your main function looks something like this:

```
def main():
    url = 'http://www.reddit.com/images/logo.png'
    if download_image(url):
        print('script successful!')
    else:
        print('download failed...')
```

It is by having nice, modular code, where individual parts are responsible for small jobs, that you will have lots of opportunity to check for failures and successes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use try-except, something like this.

Set some path of your script to be executed.

file_path = "C:\\python\\your_script.py"

```
try:
    #Execute the script
    execfile(file_path)
    print 'script successful'

except Exception, err:
    print 'Error from your_script: ', err
    print 'script failed'
```

Useful article for Python Exception Handling Techniques.

http://doughellmann.com/2009/06/python-exception-handling-techniques.html